# check for an Array in a dictionary and return the UIImage of the dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary example : 
1)

```js
var dict = [["A":UIImage(named: "A.png"),"B":UIImage(named: "B.png"),"C":UIImage(named: "C.png")]
```

And I have an array : 
2)

```js
var array = ["A", "C", "K", "B"]
```

I want to check in my dictionary this array and return me an array of UIImage of the dictionary  in the same order to my array and if it exist in my dict and  put empty when it doesn't find the image

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Iterate over the array, and collect the images associated in another array.

```
 var images = [UIImage]()
    for key in array {
       if let image = dict[key] {
          images.append(image)
    }
    }
```

//images now will contain the images in the order of the keys specified in array.

**EDIT**:

If you want even the nil items to be in the array, then you need to have an array of optional image objects.

```
 var images = [UIImage?]()
    for key in array {
          images.append(dict[key])
    }

  //While fetching the items, ensure you unwrap them-
  //for example- the following tries to fetch and unwrap images from this array
   for image in images {
      if let image = image {
        //Do something with the image
      }else {
        //The image was not present.
      }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! I will have an array of UIImage ? with a print("\(images)") ?

Comment: No, it will be unwrapped by the 'if let image', you will have actual image objects not optionals

Comment: I tried but it's not in the same order how it can be possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by same order? @Mams1101? It should be in the order of the keys given in the array right?

Comment: Yes that's what I want like in the same order like the  var array, how can I check the key of dictionary is equivalent to the array  with a query ?

Comment: Can you add when it's empty put empty or something like that ? I will accept your answer after that thanks !!